# Points in Polygon with ArcGIS-REST-JS library

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, node-js

I am trying to get the points in polygon with Node JS libraries. Using Simple JS, I can get using QueryTask. But there is no queryTask in Node lib.

```
var queryFeat = require('@esri/arcgis-rest-feature-layer');
    var abc = queryFeat.queryFeatures({
        url: "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/1",
        where: `OBJECTID = 2`
    }).then((res)=>{
        res.features.forEach((feat) => {
            console.log("ASDFGHJK:::: "+feat.attributes.OBJECTID);
            var xyz = queryFeat.queryFeatures({
                url: "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/0",
                returnGeometry: true,
                outFields: ['*'],
                geometry: feat.geometry,
                spatialRel: 'esriSpatialRelContains'
            }).then((blockFeat)=>{
                console.log("Block::: "+blockFeat.features.length);
            });
       });
```

I am getting `blockFeat.features.length` equals to 1000 (maximum features in response set by administrator)

I don't know what is the issue. I'm new with Node libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have encountered a bug with [arcgis-rest-js](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-rest-js/). I have logged a [pull request](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-rest-js/pull/592), which depending on if I'm right, it may be fixed in a future version of arcgis-rest-js. (***Edit: this is now [fixed in v2.1.1 of arcgis-rest-js](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-rest-js/pull/592#issuecomment-511527417)***)

In the mean-time, a workaround is to use the "params" object like this:

```
var queryFeat = require('@esri/arcgis-rest-feature-layer');
var abc = queryFeat.queryFeatures({
  url: "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/1",
  where: `OBJECTID = 2`
}).then((res) => {
  res.features.forEach((feat) => {
    console.log("ASDFGHJK:::: " + feat.attributes.OBJECTID);
    var xyz = queryFeat.queryFeatures({
      url: "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/0",
      returnGeometry: true,
      outFields: ['*'],
      params: {
        geometry: feat.geometry,
        geometryType: 'esriGeometryPolygon',
        spatialRel: 'esriSpatialRelContains'
      }
    }).then((blockFeat) => {
      console.log("Block::: " + blockFeat.features.length);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Note: this is now fixed in v2.1.1 of arcgis-rest-js